# Display Now date and Time in SQl table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I want to be able to have todays date and time now in a table column
If my table is say Table1, basically it should display the time and date when 
`SELECT * FROM Table1` is run.

I've tried the following but they just show the time from the moment in time I assign the value to column

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
ADD TodaysDate DateTime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
ADD TodaysDate DateTime

UPDATE Table1
SET TodaysDate = GETDATE()
```

Hope this is clear. any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: All column having same Date... 
a) add a computed column..
b)or Select *,Getdate() from Table1 will return the same result in fetch

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server you can use a computed column:

```
alter table table1 add TodaysDate as (cast(getdate() as date));
```

(use just `getdate()` for the date and time)

This adds a "virtual" column that gets calculated every time it is referenced.  The use of such a thing is unclear.   Well, I could imagine that if you are exporting the data to a file or another application, then it could have some use for this to be built-in.

Comment: is there anyway to just have the date ? without the time part?

Comment: `Convert(date, getdate())`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this clarifies your requirement.

The SQL Server columns with default values stores the values inside the table. When you select the values from table, the stored date time will be displayed.

There are 2 options I see without adding the column to the table itself.

1. You can use `SELECT *, GETDATE() as TodaysDate FROM Table1`
2. You can create a view on top of Table 1 with additional column like
   `CREATE VIEW vw_Table1
   AS
   SELECT *, GETDATE() as TodaysDate FROM dbo.Table1`

then you can query the view like you mentioned (without column list)

`SELECT * FROM vw_Table1`

This will give you the date and time from the moment of the execution of the query.